# Bean post processor doesn't work for @MockBean beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mockito

It's hard to explain my problem, so I'll just give a code example and explain what *I think* is going wrong. Code is located at [inchestnovstackoverflow/bpp-test](https://github.com/inchestnovstackoverflow/bpp-test).

*Code is just an example and doesn't contain useful logic.*

There are several classes.
First component just contains chain of `AutowireComponent` and handle them all.

```
@Component
public class ManagedComponent implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private final List<AutowireComponent> autowireComponents = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        // just make sure that this bean created before others
    }

    public void addAutowireComponent(AutowireComponent autowireComponent) {
        autowireComponents.add(autowireComponent);
    }

    public void invokeAll() {
        autowireComponents.forEach(AutowireComponent::invoke);
    }

}

public interface AutowireComponent {

    void invoke();

}
```

Bean post processor registers all implementations of `AutowireComponent` to `ManagedComponent`.

```
@Component
public class ManagedBeanInitializerBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, 
        ApplicationContextAware {

    private ManagedComponent managedComponent;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        try {
            managedComponent = applicationContext.getBean(ManagedComponent.class);
        } catch (BeansException e) {
            // ignore
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        Object obj = BeanPostProcessor.super.postProcessBeforeInitialization(bean, beanName);

        if (obj instanceof AutowireComponent && managedComponent != null) {
            managedComponent.addAutowireComponent((AutowireComponent) obj);
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

Configuration

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class MainConfiguration {
}
```

The problem begins where I try to test `ManagedComponent`. I have an implementation of `AutowireComponent` in a test module

```
@Component
public class EmptyAutowireComponent implements AutowireComponent {

    @Override
    public void invoke() {

    }

}
```

Next class is my test

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MainConfiguration.class)
class ManagedComponentTests {

    @Autowired
    private ManagedComponent managedComponent;

    @MockBean
    private EmptyAutowireComponent emptyAutowireComponent;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        managedComponent.invokeAll();
        Mockito.verify(emptyAutowireComponent).invoke();
    }

}
```

Bean post processor doesn't process `EmptyAutowireComponent` and doesn't register it to `ManagedComponent`. If I use `@Autowire` instead of `@MockBean`, then BPP works correct, but I have no mock instance and can't check that the method was invoked.

Is this expected behaviour that BPP doesn't configure `@MockBean` instance? Perhaps I did something wrong.

Comment: @dariosicily Did you change your edit after you first submitted it? Curious because of this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411761/6083675

Comment: @Laurel Nope, I just edited the post one time (added java tag), probably I had a second tab opened on another stack overflow page but nothing else if I remember well.